# Does Jeff Atwood sleep?

Tags: discussion, fun, jeff-atwood

I'm pretty sure Jeff lives in the US, but judging from his activity, I'm not sure. He seems to be alive at 2am(Central) and I also see him at 9am. Sure, this is 7 hours difference for him to sleep, but doesn't he have things to do like eat, look after his hygene and other things?

Clearly, a human would not have such crazy posting habits, and therefore I propose that Jeff is an alien that hates bacon and does not sleep.

On a different note, I don't see Joel often, but it's usually at around 1am.. Clearly Jeff and Joel are the same person! Hence the whole SO operation is a cover up for illegal rep gaming!! No one is safe!

Comment: http://www.sleepingtime.org/codinghorror

Comment: @Nick D: Sorry Nick, I saw your comment just after I posted my answer.

Comment: @Nick, @Mehper: i wouldn't trust that site.  they seem to think that Arizona is a time zone.  they are obviously run by those shady Ozzies.

Comment: I've posted at 4-5 in the morning (local time)...

Comment: Wait a minute, [meta-tag:bacon] and [meta-tag:vampire] are valid tags?? Meta SO really is a weird place...

Comment: @Chris you should have seen it before tag synonyms. We also had tags for random people, tags like "always-friday-in-iceland" and other random things. But those days of jokes-gone-too-far are gone, sadly

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to his Twitter activity, he is more likely to sleep between **4 a.m.** and **12 p.m.** (or 8 hours)

Here is the [link](http://www.sleepingtime.org/codinghorror) to the source.

Comment: Kinda Creepy...

Comment: @kyle, the site? indeed

Comment: That's a neat site

Comment: @Jon_Skeet is a 9-5'er! http://www.sleepingtime.org/jonskeet

Comment: @rlb.usa: I'm not surprised. I've learned that, among other things, in the long run it's regular sleep what makes you most productive. (But then, I'm old, and Jon isn't.)

Comment: 12 *p*.m., right?

Comment: Kinda tempted to rollback now. ;) @Anna

Comment: what's wrong about that? at least he has regular sleeping hours (not many of us do)

Comment: "The sleeping pattern was determined after analyzing the last **666** tweets of codinghorror. The person is located in Bay Area, CA that follows the Arizona time zone."

Answer (score 25):

Some birds sleep with half of their brain at a time while making long migration trips. Perhaps Jeff has mastered this art - during the hours when both hemispheres are available, he programs. When he's working with only one hemisphere, he participates in Meta :)

Comment: I've never seen someone use more tact and subtlety to call someone else a birdbrain...!  ;-P

Comment: @Pollyanna Calling somebody "birdbrained" in this context isn't exactly an insult ;) Context. Context. Context.

Comment: This goes a long way toward explaining why so many cases come back `status-norepro` or `status-bydesign`.

Answer (score 17):

No.  Of course not.  Sleep is just an inefficient replacement for caffeine.

Answer (score 13):

I understand he has a baby, so he probably can't count on keeping any sort of realistic sleep schedule at all.

[image: here, have a bunny baby!]
<sub>(source: [pollsb.com](http://www.pollsb.com/photos/o/35035-baby_bunny.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Where's the waffle?  There should be a waffle.  Why don't I see a waffle?

Comment: the baby ate it; check back later

Comment: @steven: hahahaha that's good!

Comment: @steven - I'm stealing that for future use

Comment: @antony - that could be misinterpreted..

Comment: One baby bunny, two baby bunnies, three ... zzzZZzzz

Answer (score 7):

This question is too esay.

Your answer: **NO**.

I recommend you not to believe the other answers!

Comment: My answer is "no"? You're right! I do *not* need sleep!