# Any plans for celebrating the 2 million?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-count

It seems we will soon hit 2 million questions. Are there any plans to mark the big thing?

Have or not, it is such a great achievement for the community. Keep up the good work guys!

Comment: This is significant to me, because I remember that back in 2008 when SO first launched, the hyphen site was just about to celebrate it's 2 millionth question.

Comment: Will Jeff finally [take a nap?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47439/does-jeff-atwood-sleep)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to celebrate reaching `2^21`?

Comment: @Joeh Coehoorn: By "hyphen site", do you mean Expert Sex Change?

Comment: @joel the wikipedia article for e-e references the link to the "two million solutions on Experts Exchange" as http://www.experts-exchange.com/twoMillionSolutions.jsp but it's a dead page -- archive has it though: http://goo.gl/f3lzY

Answer (score 10):

> > > ## [I got it! =D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221504/does-node-js-enforce-a-minimum-delay-for-settimeout)

[image: screenshot]

Close it at your peril. (:

Edit: [Perilous!](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7221504/timeline)

Comment: nicely done, though that might have been 'shopped

Comment: I feel sad for the other guy who got the 2,000,001th question